# Spring Batch allow only one instance at time

Tags: spring-batch

I want to allow to run only 1 batch run at time. I tried to find it by using this code (from job listener):

```
Set<JobExecution> jobExecutions = jobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions(jobExecution.getJobInstance().getJobName());

if (jobExecutions.size() > 1)
  System.exit(2);
```

When I run 2 batches from different terminals this code doesn't work.

P.S. In dev environment I use HSQL.

Comment: Are your jobExplorer reading the same database from every terminal?

Comment: Are your jobRepository and jobExplorer pointing to same DB? I dont see any other reason for your code to fail. what you want to achieve for that you need single DB and make sure everyone is pointing to same DB.

Comment: The problem was that I use HSQL and every time when I launch app from terminal it creates a new DB in RAMs. Problem fixed when I changed it to mySQL DB.